# How do you read HTML in Pandas with a dynamic table with no updating URL?

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm fetching data from https://www.wowprogress.com/ and am using Pandas to do it. I read the HTML into a dataframe, and counted the tables on the page. The table I want is the first table with indexes from 1 through 20, and so on.

The issue is that there's a "next" button on the page that you can press... but the URL doesn't change at all.

The code I used below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from unicodedata import normalize

table_wow = pd.read_html('https://www.wowprogress.com/')
print (table_wow)
```

This shows the first table on the page from my end. But I cannot figure out how to simulate pressing the next button and getting the rest of the data on pages 2 through whatever page I want.

Any tips on how this can be done, or what I may be missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When checking [network activity](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/) you can see that the next page is loaded from `https://www.wowprogress.com/pve/rating/next/0/rating/`, with the integer after `/next/` increasing with the page numbers. So you can loop through the subsequent pages:

```
import pandas as pd
import time

table_wow = pd.read_html('https://www.wowprogress.com/')[1]

max_page = 10

for i in range(0,max_page):
    table = pd.read_html(f'https://www.wowprogress.com/pve/rating/next/{i}/rating/')[1]
    table_wow = table_wow.append(table, ignore_index=True)
    time.sleep(1.5)
```

Comment: How did you figure out the next page? when I check the network activity, the page is updating super, super fast and everything is moving around too fast for my eyes to keep up with. Shows so much activity.

Comment: Copy the curl request of the `rating` page that loads when clicking next. You can find the url there.

Comment: Ok that works. Very neat. Is there any method of keeping the color data, Red vs Blue? Didn't realize the exported table data wouldn't even have this data at all. It may be lost unfortunately which is ok but figured I would ask.

Comment: You can't do that with `pandas`. You'll have to write a custom parser with - for example - `BeautifulSoup` to extract the color information from the `class` attribute.